# How to configure header filters in a HoloViz Panel Tabulator widget?

Tags: python, tabulator, holoviz, holoviz-panel

I am using [Panel](https://panel.holoviz.org/index.html) from HoloViz to create a dashboard web application. I am using Panel's Tabulator widget to display a table of records. Panel's Tabulator widget is based on the [Tabulator](http://tabulator.info) javascript library.

I would like to add a [header filter](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.9/filter#header) to my Panel Tabulator widget, similar to the one pictured below. It is a text box that lets your filter table records and is shown as part of the table's column headers.

[image: Tabulator table with header filter highlighted]

I've seen no mention of this feature in the Panel reference docs. Is there a way to get it done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that seems more a question for the "Panel" developers who have forked Tabulator ? in "pure" Tabulator, the column definition has a headerFilter parameter to add all sorts of [headerFilter](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.9/columns#definition)